# Monitor connected through VGA to HDMI converter not always detected

Tags: nvidia, graphics, multiple-monitors, hdmi, vga

I recently bought a new laptop which does not have VGA output. Since my second monitor has only a VGA input I bought a VGA/HDMI converter.

Some important information about my laptop: Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS, graphic cards : Nvidia GeForce 930M (with the latest drivers for ubuntu), and I also have an integrated Intel 5500 HD graphics card.

The first day I used my new laptop with that monitor everything was working perfectly either in windows or in ubuntu. But after the second booting the monitor was not detected anymore (in windows and ubuntu). I tried to go to display setting and try to "detect" the monitor but it does not work as it worked before. The monitor itself displays "no video input".

The only way I have to make it work is to continuously reboot my laptop until its detected (a little bit strange, but it can be a hint to the problem).

I don't know what I can do, anyone has an idea or had the same problem?

Kind regards,
Edgar

Comment: if both windows and ubuntu cant detect it then it should not be an OS issue. Hardware issue is more accurate.

Answer (score 0):

Try, After to connect, VGA/HDMI, I going to "System Settings" -> "Display"; and worked for me.

I hope help you.